# Can decimals less than one omit the first zero?

Tags: números, número-gramatical

I'm trying to format some text for my company's pricing page.

If we want to express a number that would be written 0.005 in English, my understanding is that it would be written 0,005 in Spanish.

In English, our page currently omits the leading zero, e.g., "They cost .005 dollars per unit."  In Spanish, is it acceptable to write, "Ellos cuestan ,005 dólares por unidad." or is the leading zero required in this case?

BTW, we only have one Spanish translation, so I don't have any further information about which nation or region this is for.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked but to me dropping the initial zero in English looks ugly and can read to possible mistakes like reading .45 as 45

Comment: One wonders what costs 0.005 per unit. You always need a leading zero.

Comment: Is this a technical page (e.g., engineering, industry)? Perhaps it's better to "translate" in they way most of your target audience expects/prefers, rather than for a general audience. For example, while I consider 0,005 standard in Spanish, I prefer 0.005 in source code no matter what.

Comment: Whatever the eventual Answer, how could you think about Asking such a thing here, rather than within your own organisation?

Consider what might happen if anyone gave what you saw as a perfect Answer, you used that for weeks, days or even hours on company documents and then your boss disagreed?

Ignoring English, Spanish or any language, first Ask whoever is in charge of your in-house style.

If you get no help there, compose a clearly consistent style and submit it upwards for approval.

Consider basing such a style on Pablo H's Comment, above.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I agree. People trust the Stack Exchange but, as is the case with the Internet in general, they should know that the information provided may be wrong and should be double-checked at all times. It's not a question a blindly relying on what anyone can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, está mal. El cero siempre antes de la coma (o el punto, lo que prefieras).

Comment: Hay varias asunciones en la respuesta que son opiniones personales, pero que no reflejan la normativa oficial ni justifican de manera suficiente por qué debería optarse por esa opción en lugar de la normativa oficial.

Comment: Pues me parece que la respuesta es perfecta. Va al grano de la pregunta:  
- _is the leading zero required?_  
- No, está mal.  
Es cierto que hay otras que documentan la afirmación, pero también hay otras que se andan por las ramas sobre si puntos o comas, que no están en la pregunta.

Comment: @aerobiomat Comencé respondiendo lo contrario a lo que está ahora, por eso. En realidad quiero borrar la respuesta pero no puedo porque está aceptada. Es literalmente lo peor que te puede pasar en SE. Ya quiero ver ese documento del OP sin los ceros antes de las comas a ver cómo queda xd

Comment: Pues qué risa :-)

Answer (score 10):

En los [Cuadernos de la Fundación Dr. Antonio Esteve](https://www.esteve.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/13230.pdf), Normas que regulan la escritura científica, podemos leer:

> Un número decimal nunca podrá comenzar por la coma decimal, por más que en inglés
> podamos encontrar cosas como .05 o .49 cuando el número entero es cero. Lo correcto es, en cualquier idioma, 0,05 y 0,49, respectivamente, porque los números decimales siempre empiezan por la parte entera aunque sea cero.

Lo mismo dice la UNE (Asociación Española de Normalización), tal como se recoge en [este apunte universitario](https://medi.usal.edu.ar/archivos/medi/docs/17-como_se_separan_los_miles-convertido.pdf):

[image: USAL]

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta correcta y aceptada.

Answer (score 7):

According to *FundéuRAE*, both periods and commas are valid:

> El signo para separar los decimales al expresar un número en cifras puede ser un punto o una coma.
> Ambos signos tienen uso en los países hispanohablantes, pero en México y el Caribe se prefiere el punto, según la costumbre anglosajona, mientras que en España y el Cono Sur se prefiere la coma, según la costumbre francoalemana.
> Por este motivo, en la Ortografía de la lengua española, de las Academias de la Lengua, se señala que, «con el fin de promover un proceso tendente hacia la unificación, se recomienda el uso del punto como signo separador de los decimales», al tiempo que aclara que la coma sigue siendo igualmente válida, de modo que puede escribirse tanto 11.5 como 11,5 para la cantidad de ‘once y medio’.

<sub>*Source [FundéuRAE](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/decimales-coma-y-punto-son-ambas-validas/)*</sub>

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta tiene dos partes, el segundo párrafo es una duda aquí respondida

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer provided by Ananias. I was going to just comment but I can't include images properly. So ...

For the leading zeros part, in Spain we don't remove the leading zeroes in general (maybe in obscure scientific papers, but not in "real life" situations)

Below you can find an example of some typical offers from a supermarket

[image: supermarket]

Comment: El problema no es como se coloca en España o en español, sino como es correcto en cada moneda, los precios en dólares son totalmente diferente que en Euros. De hecho en dólares es permisivo no colocar las unidades mientras que en euros parece ser incorrecto. También el símbolo de dólar va delante de la cifra mientras que en euros el símbolo va detrás. Para mi es una pregunta off-topic, refiere más a escritura de monedas (currency) que a idiomas.

Comment: @Danielillo No es una cuestión de monedas, sino de idiomas. Mientras que en inglés es habitual omitir el cero antes del punto decimal, en español no es correcto.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en países como USA con flyers de ventas de las super cadenas en inglés y español, solo se hace la traducción del texto, no de cada precio.

Comment: @Gustavson in fact for prices I think we would write 75p not .75 pounds.